# How do I close Modal Popup on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a modal popup to change the password and I need to close it on submit button.

```
<div class="modal-body"> 
    <?php if(isset($message))echo '<span class="text-success txt-upper" style="margin-left:2rem;">'. $message .'</span>';?>

    <?php echo form_open('',array('class'=>'ajaxForm')); ?>
      <fieldset class="table "> 
        <div class="form-group">
        <?php $class = form_error('newpassword')?"input-error":"" ?>
          <div  class="col-md-12" style="margin: 10px 0"><?php echo form_password('newpassword','','class="form-control margin-both-0 '. $class.'" id="newpassword"  placeholder="New Password" autocomplete="off"'); ?><?php echo form_error('newpassword'); ?></div>            
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <?php $class = form_error('conpassword')?"input-error":"" ?>
          <div class="col-md-12 " style="margin: 10px 0"><?php echo form_password('conpassword','','class="form-control  margin-both-0 '. $class.'" id="conpassword"  placeholder="Confirm Password" autocomplete="off"'); ?><?php echo form_error('conpassword'); ?></div>           
        </div>  

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
        <?php echo form_submit('submit_btn', 'Change Password', 'class="submit btn btn-success margin-left-4p pad-1-rem margin-bottom-10"'); ?>
     </fieldset>
    <?php echo form_close();?>  
  </div>
```

The above code is the form submit button.

```
$(function() {
        $(".submit").click(function(e){
            var sdata = $('.ajaxForm').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data:sdata,
                url: "<?php echo site_url('home/change_password'); ?>",
                success: function(data){
                    $('#baseModal-xs .modal-content').html(data);  
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".submit").ajaxForm(function() { 
        window.close();
    });
```

This is the javascript I have added the windows.close function isn't working

Comment: Are you using bootstrap3? if so, $('.modal').modal('hide');

Comment: Try to close it from parent window.

Comment: @anmarti how do i do that?

Comment: Do you have an error? How do you open your popup?

Comment: ItayB's answer worked, Thanks a lot.
@Romuleald No Error I just wanted it to close on submit, It opens when I select the option to change password and that links to a popup modal

Comment: $('.modal').modal('toggle')

Comment: @davidnoronha I've added it's as a solution, it would be great if you mark it as solve :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your code it seems like you are using twitter-bootstrap-3. Then, I would stick to their API suggested here: [Bootstrap JavaScript Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)
 and call the modal method to close/hide the visible modal:

```
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```

Comment: this should be a comment.

Comment: although it solved the problem but this is not very informative, what was the issue? and why should OP use this code? If you add more then it will be a complete answer and i would love to upvote it.

Comment: @Jai Is it correct now? (thanks for your review, by the way :-) )

Comment: @ItayB just one problem it kinds hides on failed validation too

Comment: @davidnoronha Than you should add if statement and call this method only when validate..

Comment: it is pointing to success already right? Like success: function(data)

Comment: so that should go in an if/else statement?

Comment: No, if you are taking that approach no if/else needed. Just Goolge: jQuery ajax, and you'll see in jQuery ajax official page examples of succees/fail/final/whatever you need

Answer (score 0):

Just call the below code

```
$.modal.close();
```

Comment: this should be a comment.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.